# Android - creating ListView content in AsyncTask causes random crash

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I create the content of a ListView in the background and when each item is added I update the ListView adapter.Usually it works ok but some times I get this error. And strangely enough it happens 10 times more often in my Galaxy s4 mini than in my HTC Sensation. I don't understand why this happens since I clearly notify the adapter through the UI thread. Any thoughts ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView 
did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified 
from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls 
notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131100779, class 
util.TouchInterceptor) with Adapter(class com.bill.deuterh.ListActivity$ListAdapter)]
```

AsyncTask:

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for (int i=0;i<table.length;i++){
            if(isCancelled()){break;}
            myList.add(createObject(table[i])));
            ListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

(If it matters, I cast the Listview as TouchInterceptor which is a modified google class for supporting the rearrangement of the listview items with drag and drop.)

Comment: Why you don't put your `Listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` into `onProgressUpdate()` and call an update by `publishProgress`. People, the asynctask comes with UI running methods! Use them. `AsyncTask` is powerful but not in that way you use it

Comment: Set ListView Adapter in OnPostExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: If everything else has correct set up. Then this code will Show every update from your `doInBackground` immediatly in the listview = good user experience!

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i=0;i<table.length;i++){
        if(isCancelled()){break;}
        myList.add(createObject(table[i])));
        publishProgress();
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void.. values) {
ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

`OnPreExecute, onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate` are already running on the UIThread. Maybe you don't execute the asynctask the right way. That's why no data has been updated?

Comment: this seems to do the trick. I opened this activity 100 times and didn't crash so I guess it's ok now. I didn't know that OnPreExecute, onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate execute on UI thread. thank you.

Comment: @Anonymous you are welcome! If your ListView doesn't inflate again even with that Change, there must be something wrong the way you put the data to the Adapter. Once again, the `UIMethods` are one of the big powerful stuffs the `AsyncTask` Comes with! Glad to help you. Happy coding

Comment: @Anonymous regarding to Chris comment it would be better to call `publisProgress()` not every Loop run. This will cause your Screen freeze. just use it in a medium way if you don't want the user to wait for the whole Content. call `publishProgress()` about 3-4 times over the whole `doInBackground()`. i think this is perfekt!

Answer (score 0):

This should be run only once at the end of onpostexecute without the need of runonuithread.
ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

remove this:

```
   ListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

and put this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: That's a bad solution. I think he wants to Show the new data immediatly in the `listview`. Not at the end when everything is finished == bad user experience!

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged should never be run in a loop because it is very time consuming operation. This is the only reason that android developers created this function.

Comment: Mike take a look at that loop and how long do you think it takes to finish? What about the userexperience on a low processor when it freeze the screen because all the notfydatasetchanged functions?

Comment: source? i tried both, using `progressUpdate()` every Loop run, and only use it every 5 Loop run. The time consumption was about a few(2-5?) ms. If i don't Forget something. It's Long time ago.

Comment: but anyway you are right. Using this to much will freeze the Screen. A medium usage of this is the perfect way. not to wait till all of the data has been loaded and not to fire `onProgressUpdate()` every Loop run! you are right!

Comment: i notified Thread Opener about the Infos. I think a perfekt way is to update the Adapter about 3-4 times regarding to the time consumption of your whole `doInBackground()` this will not cause the Screen to freeze and it will give the user a experience of `this app is fast`. If he starts Scrolling, the listview `doInBackground()`should already have finished... because as you know, asynctask should only be used for short time operations

Comment: If every loop is a bit time consuming then your method is fine but if the loop is like he post it then he should definitely put the notifydatasetchanged like I advised him

Comment: that's up to the developer. I use it in a medium way and my data appears before everything has finished. In my opinion, this looks much better. Happy coding ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't write any code in `doInBackground(Void... params)` which relates or update the UI. For updation on UI Async's `onPostExecute(Void result)` method is used. 
So remove the adatper's notification from `doInbackGround(Void... params){}`